# An App ID with Identifier com.app.name is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload version 2.0 of my iOS app, but it will not allow me to use the same bundler identifier.

1) When I create the new app record in iTunesConnect how can I change it match my new bundle identifier, if my app has the old bundle identifier?

Comment: Are you creating a new app when you should be adding a new version of your current app?

Comment: Why are you changing the Bundle ID?

Comment: @JaredPrice I would like to create a new version of my current app but it keeps saying bundle ID is not available.

Comment: @DanielStorm I get an error to enter a different bundle ID

Comment: When you say *create a new version* you're talking about an update to an existing application, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am. I cannot push the app to iTunes Connect because my bundle identifer is different, but I also cannot reuse the same ID. @DanielStorm

Comment: In iTunes connect I see "The bundle ID must match the one you used in Xcode. It can't be changed after you upload your first build." but I cannot archive the app with the bundleID @DanielStorm

Comment: Make the Bundle ID of your 2.0 update the same as the one you originally used for 1.0.

Comment: An App ID with Identifier 'com.my.app.name' is not available. Please enter a different string.  Is the error I get when I try to do that @DanielStorm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109953/discussion-between-daniel-storm-and-samuel-williams).

Answer (score 3):

Select your projects **Build Settings** tab in Xcode. Scroll down. Select **code signing identity** and make sure **Release** is set to **iPhone Distribution: Team Name** and not **iOS Developer**.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, create a new app id in Apple Developer portal that matches your new bundle ID. You can't do this in iTunes Connect. Do that first, then create the app record in iTunes Connect (the app id you created should be available to use).